# Calling functions using inline assembly (YUL)

Tags: solidity, assembly, yul

I've been trying to figure out how to make function calls using in-line assembly (yul)

For example, I have a function _getCurrentRate() where I would like to be capable of calling from several different functions besides this one.

```
function _getCurrentRate() public view returns (uint256 multiplier) {
        assembly {
            let pe := sload(periodEnd.slot)
            let ps := sload(periodStart.slot)
            let rate := sload(compoundRate.slot)

            if lt(timestamp(), pe) {
                multiplier := add(mul(sub(timestamp(), ps), rate), 1000000000000000000)
            } 
            
            if iszero(lt(timestamp(), pe)) {
                multiplier := 2000000000000000000
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I have looked through documentation and unable to find any hint as to how to accomplish this! An example implementation of what I am talking about would look similar to this

```
function calculateSomething() public view returns (uint256 something) {
    assembly {
        let a := 123456789
        let rate := _getCurrentRate()

        something := mul(a, rate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

_getCurrentRate must be a yul function inside your assembly block which is probably not what you want in the end

```
    function calculateSomething() public view returns (uint256 something) {
    assembly {
          function _getCurrentRate() -> multiplier {
            let pe := sload(periodEnd.slot)
            let ps := sload(periodStart.slot)
            let rate := sload(compoundRate.slot)

            if lt(timestamp(), pe) {
                multiplier := add(mul(sub(timestamp(), ps), rate), 1000000000000000000)
            } 
            
            if iszero(lt(timestamp(), pe)) {
                multiplier := 2000000000000000000
            }
        }
    
    let a := 123456789
    let rate := _getCurrentRate()

    something := mul(a, rate)
    }
}
```

one solution for your problem would be the following:

```
function calculateSomething() public view returns (uint256 something) {
    uint256 rate = _getCurrentRate();
    assembly {
        let a := 123456789
        something := mul(a, rate)
    }
}
```

Comment: So, we can't call private/internal functions within yul ?